# Database for Asp.NET Core on macOS

Tags: .net, database, macos, asp.net-core-mvc

I have question regarding Visual Studio on the Mac. I currently switched from a Microsoft computer to Mac and I want to start a new project.

However I am not quite sure what database I could use and connect to my Visual Studio, I am used to the EF where I connect to MSSQL, however MSSQL is unfortunately not available on the Mac.

Are there other possibilities or 'similar' databases I could for the Mac?

Thank you,

Stefan

Comment: See [How to Install SQL Server on a Mac](http://database.guide/how-to-install-sql-server-on-a-mac/).

Answer (score 2):

There are actually a few databases for MacOS that work well with EF Core. [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html), [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/), and [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-osx-excerpt/5.7/en/osx-installation.html) have [providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/) included with EF Core and a solid history of running natively on MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL is now available on MAC. Follow [this link](https://database.guide/how-to-install-sql-server-on-a-mac/) for a guide on how to set it up.